# How to use ifNull operator with GroupOperation in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, aggregation

I want to write a query which group by `parentId` and if `parentId` is null then group by `productId`.I wrote a mongodb query which uses `$ifNull` operator inside `$group` operator to achive this, Here is the query.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
        $match:{
            $and : [
                {"tenant_id":1} 
                {"product_type":1}
            ]
        },
        {
            $group : {
                "_id":{ $ifNull: [ "$parent_id", "$product_id" ] },
                "data": {"$first" : "$$ROOT"}
            }
        },
        { $sort: {"data.created" : 1 } },
        {$limit: 4},
        {$skip:2}
    }
)
```

I want to translate this query into spring code. Following code will group by field `parentId` and that is working fine.

```
GroupOperation grpOperation = Aggregation.group("parentId")
```

But how can i write `ifNull` condition inside `group` condition somethig like this?

```
GroupOperation grpOperation = Aggregation.group( ifNull("parentId").then("productId") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                    group("parentId")
       .applyCondition(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("parentId").then("productId")))
```

Comment: Got following error : Cannot resolve method 'group(Aggregation.group(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("parentId").then("productId")))

Comment: @nik123 group(Aggregation.group()). change that and use `Aggregation.newAggregation(.group(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("parentId").then("productId")))`

Comment: Sorry, i copied wrong error, This is the error :  Cannot resolve method 'group(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ConditionalOperators.ifNull)'. @Mebin

Comment: @nik123 Updated answer. Could you please check now.

Comment: I am using `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.group()` and this can not find any `applyCondition()` method, can you please confirm? Version : `Spring-data-mongodb-2.1.4.`

Comment: @nik123 applyCondition() is available from `org.springframework.data.mongodb` `2.2.0` Refer:https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference

Comment: I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.1.4` which uses `spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6` , as well as `spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0` is not officially released, That's why i cant upgrade to `2.2.0` currently, Is there any other way to implement this?